# Upload zip file in JSF 2.2 with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, java-ee-7

In my application you can upload a zip file. Now I'd like to incorporate ajax. How can I get ajax to work with zip files?

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false"
        pt:class="form-inline" pt:role="form"
        rendered="#{consoleController.getAdmin() != null}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="file">File:</label>
            <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{uploadController.file}" />
        </div>
        <h:commandButton id="button" value="Upload"
            action="#{uploadController.upload}" class="btn btn-default">
            <f:ajax execute="file" render="@all" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

I get the following error in form of a modal window in Chrome:

```
malformedXML: Toplevel node must be one of: changes, redirect, error,...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem every time I tried to render(using ajax) forms of the type **enctype="multipart/form-data"**. 
Instead of using **render="@all"**, try to render manually the forms you want except the form "form".
Ex: **render=":form2 :form3 : form4"**